# Execute ranger command instead of shell command when opening a program in ranger

Tags: ranger

When you press <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> in ranger, it'll open the file under the cursor. What "open the file" means depends on the file type, and is defined on `rifle.conf`. However, I only know how to set it up to execute a shell command:

```
ext <filetype>, has <command> = <command> "$@"
```

How may I do the same thing for ranger's internal commands?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hack-ish, but you can remap the <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys to run the command:

```
map l eval fm.execute_console('your_command') if fm.thisfile.extension in ['filetype1', 'filetype2', 'filetype3'] else fm.move(right=1)

map <RIGHT> eval fm.execute_console('your_command') if fm.thisfile.extension in ['filetype1', 'filetype2', 'filetype3'] else fm.move(right=1)
```

*Source: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/2164*